# Datastax - Cassandra CQL Solr query pagination issue

Tags: solr, cassandra, pagination, datastax, cql

I was trying to implement pagination using solr query, but not working properly from CQL solr. Please advise me, i am new to Cassandra and solr.

**I am using cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 3.0.10.1443 | DSE 5.0.4 | CQL spec 3.4.0**

1) select country_id,country_name from rptavlview.country where solr_query='{"q":"*:*","start":"1"}' limit 5;

when i tried  with the above query, i am getting error as below

**InvalidRequest**: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="You have driver paging active which also activates Solr deep pagination. The 'start' parameter is not allowed. Please either deactivate paging or read about Solr deep paging restrictions and fix accordingly."

2) select country_id,country_name from rptavlview.country where solr_query='{"q":"*:*","start":"1","rows":"5"}';

**InvalidRequest**: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Unsupported query parameter: rows"

**When i tried from solr it worked**

http://MYIPADDRESS:8983/solr/rptavlview.country/select?q=*%3A*&start=1&rows=5&wt=json&indent=true

"response": {
    "numFound": 237,
    "start": 1,
    "docs": [
      {
        "_uniqueKey": "[\"49\",\"Christmas Island\"]",
        "country_name": "Christmas Island",
        "country_name_ar": "جزيرة كريسماس ",
        "country_id": "49"
      },
      {
        "_uniqueKey": "[\"51\",\"Colombia\"]",
        "country_name": "Colombia",
        "country_name_ar": "كولمبيا",
        "country_id": "51"
      },
      {
        "_uniqueKey": "[\"56\",\"Cuba\"]",
        "country_name": "Cuba",
        "country_name_ar": "كوبا",
        "country_id": "56"
      },
      {
        "_uniqueKey": "[\"57\",\"Cyprus\"]",
        "country_name": "Cyprus",
        "country_name_ar": "قبرص ",
        "country_id": "57"
      },
      {
        "_uniqueKey": "[\"59\",\"Democratic Republic of the Congo\"]",
        "country_name": "Democratic Republic of the Congo",
        "country_name_ar": "جمهورية الكونغو الديمقراطية",
        "country_id": "59"
      }
    ]
  }
}

why pagination is not working with my CQL solr query ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

answer for my posted question can be resolved by

**In CQL**

cqlsh> paging off;

cqlsh> select country_id,country_name from rptavlview.country where solr_query='{"q":"*:*","start":1}' limit 5;

**In Java - set Fetch Size for statement**

Statement statement = new SimpleStatement(cql_query_string);
statement.setFetchSize(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

Answer (score 3):

Solr supports [two different ways of doing pagination](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Pagination+of+Results) - one is the old `start` parameter which tells Solr at which element to start the result set, and the new one is cursorMark - which tells Solr where the last result set ended and to start presenting results from the mark and onwards.

The latter way (also referenced as "deep pagination") is the way supported by Cassandra with its `paging_state` element, so my guess is that the Solr integration will do its own pagination based on the properties given in the CQL query, and not in the JSON used as a Solr query (as it would have overwritten the properties of the query).

I've described the difference between using a paging state / cursor mark and "old style" [pagination in a different answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37790694/solr-cursor-marker-and-pagination), which should show why using the state / mark is superior in a distributed context.

Comment: 'select country_id,country_name from rptavlview.country where solr_query='{"q":"*:*","start":"1"}' limit 5; '                                                         is working fine in [cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 3.0.9.1346 | DSE 5.0.3 | CQL spec 3.4.0 | Native protocol v4]

Comment: can any one provide me with any example

Comment: i am not able to fire CQL with old start and rows parameter in DSE 5.0.4,     **select * from rptavlview.country where solr_query='{"q":"*:*","start":"5","rows":"3"}';**    , here its raising error , **InvalidRequest:** Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Unsupported query parameter: rows"

Answer (score 1):

Few basic points:

1. CQL Solr queries are defaulted to an equivalent LIMIT 10.
2. Pagination is not on by default.
3. SELECT select expression FROM table
        [WHERE solr_query = 'search expression'] [LIMIT n]

To answer your first question:
"Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="You have driver paging active which also activates Solr deep pagination. The 'start' parameter is not allowed. Please either deactivate paging or read about Solr deep paging restrictions and fix accordingly"

==> Please check "cql_solr_query_paging" property. 
    File name : DSE_install_location/resources/dse/conf/dse.yaml

```
Valid values are : 'driver' and  'off';
```

"When 'driver', DSE Search will use pagination (aka cursors) when it detects the driver is using pagination"
 "When 'off' it will ignore the driver's setting and not use pagination. In this case the query parameter 'paging' can override it."
By default its 'off'.  So, in your case current value is 'driver'.

So, you should modify your query to :

```
select country_id,country_name from rptavlview.country where solr_query='{"q":"*:*"}' limit 5;
```

OR:

```
select country_id,country_name from rptavlview.country where solr_query='{"q":"*:*","paging": null,"start":1}' limit 5;
```

With Turn off the pagination property and restart dse.

"InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Unsupported query parameter: rows"
==> Use the LIMIT clause to specify how many rows to return.

More information (please read):
https://docs.datastax.com/en/datastax_enterprise/4.8/datastax_enterprise/srch/srchCql.html

Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Hi, i tried your post. first i changed **cql_solr_query_paging: driver**, but getting the same error as before in DSE 5.0.4.      i tried the same query in DSE 5.0.3  by keeping it as default **# cql_solr_query_paging: off**, its working fine. in both cases its not working in DSE 5.0.4. my 5.0.4 cassandra runs both solr and spark, will it be the issue?

Comment: cql_solr_query_paging: off should be ok. Please leave that one as is. Then try your query.  You should be ok with solr/spark combination.Could you please tell me the query you are using when "cql_solr_query_paging: driver"?

Comment: `select country_id,country_name from rptavlview.country where solr_query='{"q":"*:*","paging": null,"start":1}' limit 5;`
**InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="You have driver paging active which also activates Solr deep pagination. The 'start' parameter is not allowed. Please either deactivate paging or read about Solr deep paging restrictions and fix accordingly."**   in dse.yaml , i have updated  
`cql_solr_query_paging:  driver`

Comment: Please remove the "start" param. I have edited my answer (removed "OR")..So, your query should be : select country_id,country_name from rptavlview.country where solr_query='{"q":"*:*","paging": null}' limit 5; Else you have to go with "cql_solr_query_paging: off"

Comment: then, how will i implement paging, ie, eg: start 10 and rows 5

Comment: Prajith:  As I said earlier, search paginates in two ways:
1. The default pagination for search uses start and rows parameters in CQL search. (it is not mandatory to provide a sort clause. However, if a sort clause is not provided, sorting is undefined)
==> This one is pretty straight forward. 
 select country_id,country_name from rptavlview.country where solr_query='{"q":"*:*","paging": null,"sort":"country_id asc","start":10}' limit 5;
 (make sure cql_solr_query_paging: off or commented out)

Comment: 2. Appropriate only for paging through deep result sets, search pagination with cursors is the transparent use of Solr cursors through CQL native protocol.

 FYI: We use cursorMark approach and PagingState approach.

Comment: i had got a solution for that, cql_solr_query_paging: off in dse.yaml for cassandra 5.0.4 and 5.0.5 does not make any difference , `cqlsh> paging off`.  after that run the query `select country_id,country_name from rptavlview.country where solr_query='{"q":"*:*","start":10}' limit 5; `